# Design of hotend of Monoprice MP Select printer

Tags: monoprice-select-mini, part-identification

I am not an expert and I may use slightly wrong terminology here.  Please assume I have used the incorrect term if something I say does not quite add up. I have a Monoprice MP Select printer which had some PLA go brittle and really jam up the feed in the hot-end.

While trying to clear the hotend - including removing stuff from inside the hotend heatsink a small, dark grey/black, round washer with outer diameter of about 5 mm fell out the bottom of the machine.  I'm scratching my head as to where, if anywhere this belongs on the machine.  It is entirely likely that this is not from the hot-end but fell off a pocket tool I was using without me noticing.  *Does anyone know if there are any small washers associated with the hotend?*

I ask if anyone knows if this is part of the printer because subsequent to my clearing the head, the printer is not printing properly - everything still works - kind-of - just prints are messier.   I initially had problems with getting the print to stick to the bed at all until I readjusted the bed - something I have not had to do before, and I'm unsure why I would suddenly need to.   I'm posit it could simply relate to pressure  I may have inadvertently applied while clearing the hotend and the fairly fine tolerances, but I don't know enough to know if it is actually due to a missing part!

---

Additionally, I've been unable to find an explosion/tear-down/parts visualisation for this printer or hot end - if anyone knows of any that would be very useful, although that's not my question.

Comment: What is the inner diameter? 3 mm?

Comment: photos of the hotend and the washer might help.